# Access database engine cannot update that data in table

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to insert a new row into the table Project in a GUI on C#.  When I click "create project" and it runs the method, this error shows up:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The Microsoft Office Access database engine
>   cannot update the data in Project.

I have some triggers in my database, but I don't think that is the cause of the issue.  When I debug the program in Visual Studio and plug my SQL statement directly into Access, it works just fine, but for some reason when I use the `OleDbConnection` it messes up.

This is the SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Project (projectType, projectStatus, projectStartDate, projectDueDate, projectRate, clientNo, accountNo) 
VALUES ('State Audit', 'In-Progress', #5/2/2015#, #5/31/2015#, 125, 8, 18);
```

And this is the code I am using:

```
public void Connect(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        dbConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        dbConn.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbConn.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Connection");
    }
}
```

Comment: How does you connection string look?

Comment: The connection string is fine, all of my other sql statements work, just not this one for some reason.

Comment: Can you dig into the exception a bit more and see if you get more information on why the insert is not is working.  One thing you can do is catch the exception `catch(Exception ex)`, so that you can examine it.

Comment: That is the neatest thing ever.  I didn't know you could do that.  Thanks for the info!  The error said: The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot update the data in Project.

The minimum required version to update the data is 14.0.0000.0000. I'm assuming that means I just need to update the version?

Comment: It could, but it doesn't match that "all of my other sql statements work". It could also mean that you should or could adjust your connection string to the version that matches your actual database file.

Comment: Maybe the DB is occupied? try to close all the proccess/applications that might be using it (ms-access, web applications, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem updating an Access table using a Delphi application.  I found the problem was a Data Macro.

I created the table and was initially able to update and insert into without a problem using the Delphi application.  I then assigned an AfterUpdate Data Macro to the table.  That caused me to receive a similar error to the one you experienced although it worked fine in Access.  Removing the macro did not solve the problem.  I ended up deleting the table and recreating it.  That solved the problem.  Fortunately, I was just testing to see whether the Data Macro would work with my application.